# Animation while moving

Tags: animation

I am an absolute beginner started a couple days ago. I downloaded one of Mixamos walking animation, and put it on,"stay in place" before I downloaded it. its working fine. but how do I move that animation from one location to another while doing the animation? also,lets say I want my character to walk then gradually start to run using a walk and run animation from Mixamo, how would I do that?